# How to dynamically change text according to what is elected in the select tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, web

I have made a select tag and a textarea and i want so that when i choose one thing in the select it will update the textarea here is what i tried:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once ('../includes/connection.php');
include_once ('../includes/article.php');
$artikel = new Artikel;
$artikler = $artikel->fetch_all();
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['indhold'])) {

$titel = $_GET['titel'];
$indhold = $_GET['indhold'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (empty($titel) or empty($indhold)) {
$error = 'Alle felter skal udfyldes';
header('location: edit.php');
} else {
    $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE artikler SET artikel_titel = ?, artikel_indhold = ?,sidst_opdateret = ? WHERE artikel_id = ?');
$query->bindValue(1, $titel);
$query->bindValue(2, $indhold);
$query->bindValue(3, time());
$query->bindValue(4, $id);
$query->execute();
header('location: edit.php');
exit();
}
    } else {
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ændre side</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/billeder/book.png">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <h4>Ændre side</h4>
    <br>
    <form action="edit.php" method="get">
        <select name="id" onChange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="[null]"></option>
    <?php foreach($artikler as $artikel) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $artikel['artikel_id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $artikel['artikel_titel']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <br>
  <form action="edit.php" method="GET">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="titel" placeholder="Ny Titel">
    <br>
        <textarea name="indhold" cols="50" rows="15" placeholder="Indhold"><?php echo $artikel['artikel_indhold']; ?></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Ændre">
  </form>
  <a href="index.php" id="logo">&larr;Tilbage</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} }
 ?>
```

i dont really know how to do it and i do not have any ideas plz help me im beginning to become a little desperate
Thanks to everyone who helps or tries to help or upvote or lays a comment :) Cheers

Comment: 1) write sql query 2) execute query 3) retrieve results 4) display results 5) ??? 6) profit

Comment: This topic need to search for php tutorials. Try [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+database+tutorial&oq=php+database+&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0j69i61j0l3.12075j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) on Google

Comment: @MarcB I have updated this if you could figure this out for me
Then you are very kind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you created a `$mysqli` object through `$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $db)`, use this:

PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT `article_content` FROM articles WHERE artikel_id='1'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

HTML:.

```
<span class="text"><?php echo nl2br($row['article_content'])?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT article_content FROM articles WHERE artikel_id = 1
```